# Exception thrown when starting localstack

Tags: localstack

I'm doing this on mac, and before I start localstack, I ran `pip install --upgrade localstack`.  Then, I did `localstack start`.  Then I got below exception

```
Starting local dev environment. CTRL-C to quit.
Starting mock API Gateway (http port 4567)...
Starting mock DynamoDB (http port 4569)...
Starting mock SES (http port 4579)...
Starting mock Kinesis (http port 4568)...
Starting mock Redshift (http port 4577)...
Starting mock S3 (http port 4572)...
Starting mock CloudWatch (http port 4582)...
Starting mock CloudFormation (http port 4581)...
Starting mock SSM (http port 4583)...
Starting mock SQS (http port 4576)...
Starting local Elasticsearch (http port 4571)...
Starting mock SNS (http port 4575)...
Starting mock DynamoDB Streams service (http port 4570)...
Starting mock Firehose service (http port 4573)...
Starting mock Route53 (http port 4580)...
Starting mock ES service (http port 4578)...
Starting mock Lambda service (http port 4574)...
2017-11-23T16:12:41:ERROR:localstack.services.generic_proxy: Error forwarding request: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4564): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10719d1d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)) Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/localstack/services/generic_proxy.py", line 181, in forward
    headers=forward_headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 112, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 508, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4564): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10719d1d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))
```

I actually checked if there's any process is listening on 4564 by `lsof -n -iTCP:4564 | grep LISTEN`, but nothing returned.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/213):

```
DEBUG=1 localstack start
```

In the logg before erroring out You may find a path containing: localstack.ddb.zip (replace *some_path* below)
Remove that file and also remove the dynamodb package from localstack/infra.

```
rm -f /var/folders/some_path/localstack.ddb.zip
rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/localstack/infra/dynamodb/
```

Now you can try localstack start again.

*Furthermore: I am seeing the same issue when I run in docker, but there I can't remove anything since the container is created from an image on every compose-up.*